# Error while training a ML model in Watson Knowledge Studio

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, watson-knowledge-studio

Error: "Machine learning model training process failed. Cannot call the training service."

I have 2 sets with 8 and 6 documents in each and all documents annotated successfully, submitted and accepted.

However, training always fails with above error. Re-login, different browsers etc. all tried but din't work.

Comment: Same question asked here too-https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/431066/error-when-training-machine-learning-model-trainin/

Answer (score 0):

It worked now. Looks like the server was down for a while. Thanks!